# [R]:Can the time below in opening a 7GB csv be further reduced from 17 min to less than a minute

Tags: r, data.table

My code snippet and time taken data is as below.

any suggestions and alternate options  on how to reduce the below to less than a minute maximum.

```
##########RUN FROM r 64bit windows 10########################### 

> #automation to import large clog data into R
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  363072 19.4     592000 31.7   460000 24.6
Vcells 6672707 51.0   10309224 78.7  7293876 55.7
> memory.limit(size=20000)
[1] 20000
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4
  The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
  Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and browseVignettes("data.table")
  Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com
> DT <- fread("C:/CLOG-BIG-DATA-PROJECT/WestBengal_0000.txt",sep=",",header=FALSE,
              showProgress = TRUE,verbose=TRUE )

###############################################################

#output#########################################################


**17502188 rows and 64 (of 64) columns from 7.143 GB file in 00:17:38**
Read 17502188 rows. Exactly what was estimated and allocated up front
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map (rerun may be quicker)
   0.000s (  0%) sep and header detection
  18.283s (  2%) Count rows (wc -l)
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection (100 rows at 10 points)
  19.296s (  2%) Allocation of 17502188x64 result (xMB) in RAM
**1019.676s ( 93%) Reading data**
   0.107s (  0%) Allocation for type bumps (if any), including gc time if triggered
   0.048s (  0%) Coercing data already read in type bumps (if any)
  39.639s (  4%) Changing na.strings to NA
**1097.049s        Total**
```

Comment: Do you need all columns to be read?

Comment: yes..i do need all of them..surely

Comment: I was once suggested to use `colClasses = "character"`.

Comment: > gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  824226 44.1    1442291 77.1  1168576 62.5
Vcells 7819076 59.7   12885927 98.4  9030896 69.0
> memory.limit(size=20000)
[1] 20000
> library(data.table)
> DT <- fread("C:/CLOG-BIG-DATA-PROJECT/WestBengal_0000.txt",sep=",",header=FALSE,showProgress = TRUE,verbose=TRUE,colClasses = "character" )

Comment: Read 17502188 rows and 64 (of 64) columns from 7.143 GB file in 00:21:54
Read 17502188 rows. Exactly what was estimated and allocated up front
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map (rerun may be quicker)
   0.000s (  0%) sep and header detection

Comment: 23.730s (  2%) Count rows (wc -l)
   0.016s (  0%) Column type detection (100 rows at 10 points)
  30.579s (  2%) Allocation of 17502188x64 result (xMB) in RAM
1259.631s ( 93%) Reading data
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation for type bumps (if any), including gc time if triggered
   0.000s (  0%) Coercing data already read in type bumps (if any)
  44.165s (  3%) Changing na.strings to NA
1358.121s        Total

Comment: surprisingly with colClasses= "character"...time increased by 4 minutes taking it to 21:54

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: @amonk... i read the link you refered ..earlier alredy in full detail and thought data.table will be the savior.. but i am struck...i m looking for comments with real data and benchmark .. setting me a possibility that sub 1 minute will be possible

Comment: @rajibc I see what you mean. Well https://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/  might help as well

Comment: @rajibc as a last resort, I would suggest Rcpp and some custom function involving `fseek` as well? My 2 cents

Comment: @amonk thanks...let me explore Rcpp path...

Comment: @rajibc if you don't mind share you Big file, I ll do some hacks and get back to you :)

Comment: How fast is it if you set `verbose = FALSE` and `showProgress = FALSE`?

Comment: In my experience it is not possible to carve that much space out of a csv import or table that large. The reason that  using colClasses="character" added time, is because R converts characters to factors and imports the levels, which are integers (almost always less memory per factor) and adds the labels based on the level once it is imported. By forcing character you actually give it more work to do.  The initial import on a set like this is foreboding, but once loaded you can save as Rdata and load in under a minute.

Comment: @amnok it s a 10GB  zipped upload...let me get back to you ..BTW is it ok if i give you a stripped version?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you define the column types in advance? Another option would be to split up the file into smaller chunks. That's what I had to do, since I was running into memory issues.

Comment: @amonk.. i manged to upload the zipped version  https://ufile.io/rr7kj. 
 ..have a look for the hack...thnks

Answer (score 0):

Curious to see if this scales with your dataset:

```
# These 2 lines load the data.
f <- file('C:/data.txt', 'r');
d <- readLines(f);

# Some restructuring:
splitToVec <- function(x){unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\t"))}
processedData <- lapply(d, FUN = splitToVec);
close(f);
```

Now the first element of `processedData` is a vector containing the column headers, and the other elements contain the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very simple solution: switch to the latest dev version of `data.table`. There were literally dozens of speed improvements in fread since version 1.10.4 that you have, most important one is switch to parallel file reading.

For example, on my laptop I have a 2.7Gb CSV file with 13M rows x 35 columns (roughly 2.5 times smaller than yours). It takes only 15.7s to read it with the current latest version of R data.table. Assuming your file has a similar structure, it should take approximately 40s for `fread` to ingest it.

Comment: =============================
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map 8.040GB file
   0.000s (  0%) sep=',' ncol=64 and header detection
   0.099s (  0%) Column type detection using 10062 sample rows
 109.781s (  9%) Allocation of 19920627 rows x 64 cols (12.239GB)
1180.483s ( 91%) Reading 8232 chunks of 1.000MB (2421 rows) using 4 threads
   =    0.378s (  0%) Finding first non-embedded \n after each jump
   +   19.883s (  2%) Parse to row-major thread buffers
   + 1160.034s ( 90%) Transpose

Comment: +    0.187s (  0%) Waiting
   0.000s (  0%) Rereading 0 columns due to out-of-sample type exceptions
1290.363s        Total..........................new result with 1.10.5 dev version of data. table.....@Pasha S... anyidea what is Transpose and why it spends so much time 90% with it?

Comment: @rajibc "Transpose" involves writing the data out into the R data structures. If it takes this much time, it would usually indicate there are many distinct character values in your data, and is caused by the mechanism of how R stores strings internally (in a giant hash table). I don't think there is much that can be done about this...

Comment: yes.. i moved to python+spark...am clocking around 3.5  minutes ... sub 1 minute still a far cry...-